# Python3: Tkinter and buggy scales

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

For a project I'm working on I needed to create a way for the user to specify a range of numbers but for that range to make sense (ie. not having a minimum higher than a maximum), for this I created "double sliders", where the value of one affects the range of the other (and vice versa).

This works fine (code below) however I get some weird behaviour when I have two sets of double sliders (lets call these sets X and Y for conciseness), such as that when I raise XLower's value above 10 and let go it will reduce back down to 10, also the 2 Lower sliders seem to be interacting with each other.

Code for the double sliders:

```
        self.varHPLower = tk.IntVar()
        self.varHPLower = 0
        self.varHPUpper = tk.IntVar()
        self.varHPUpper = 250
        self.sclHPLower = tk.Scale(self, command=self.updatedHPLowerScale, variable=self.varHPLower, from_=self.varHPLower, to=self.varHPUpper, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, resolution=10, bg='#ffef82', width=10)
        self.sclHPLower.place(x=100, y=320, width=570, height=40)
        self.sclHPLower.set(self.varHPLower)
        self.sclHPUpper = tk.Scale(self, command=self.updatedHPUpperScale, variable=self.varHPUpper, from_=self.varHPLower, to=self.varHPUpper, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, resolution=10, bg='#ffef82', width=10)
        self.sclHPUpper.place(x=100, y=360, width=570, height=40)
        self.sclHPUpper.set(self.varHPUpper)

        self.lblHPLowerLeftLabel = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.varHPLower), anchor='w', bg='#ffef82')
        self.lblHPLowerLeftLabel.place(x=75, y=330, width=25, height=20)
        self.lblHPLowerRightLabel = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.varHPUpper), anchor='w', bg='#ffef82')
        self.lblHPLowerRightLabel.place(x=670, y=330, width=25, height=20)
        self.lblHPUpperLeftLabel = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.varHPLower), anchor='w', bg='#ffef82')
        self.lblHPUpperLeftLabel.place(x=75, y=370, width=25, height=20)
        self.lblHPUpperRightLabel = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.varHPUpper), anchor='w', bg='#ffef82')
        self.lblHPUpperRightLabel.place(x=670, y=370, width=25, height=20)
        self.lblHPRange = tk.Label(self, text='', bg='#ffef82', font=('Lucida Grande',12))
        self.lblHPRange.place(x=350, y=285, width=200, height=30)

        self.varRetreatCostLower = tk.IntVar()
        self.varRetreatCostLower = 0
        self.varRetreatCostUpper = tk.IntVar()
        self.varRetreatCostUpper = 5
        self.sclRetreatCostLower = tk.Scale(self, command=self.updatedRetreatCostLowerScale, variable=self.varRetreatCostLower, from_=self.varRetreatCostLower, to=self.varRetreatCostUpper, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, bg='#ffef82', width=10)
        self.sclRetreatCostLower.place(x=730, y=370, width=570, height=40)
        self.sclRetreatCostLower.set(self.varRetreatCostLower)
        self.sclRetreatCostUpper = tk.Scale(self, command=self.updatedRetreatCostUpperScale, variable=self.varRetreatCostUpper, from_=self.varRetreatCostLower, to=self.varRetreatCostUpper, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, bg='#ffef82', width=10)
        self.sclRetreatCostUpper.place(x=730, y=410, width=570, height=40)
        self.sclRetreatCostUpper.set(self.varRetreatCostUpper)

        self.lblRetreatCostLowerLeftLabel = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.varRetreatCostLower), anchor='w', bg='#ffef82')
        self.lblRetreatCostLowerLeftLabel.place(x=705, y=380, width=25, height=20)
        self.lblRetreatCostLowerRightLabel = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.varRetreatCostUpper), anchor='w', bg='#ffef82')
        self.lblRetreatCostLowerRightLabel.place(x=1300, y=380, width=25, height=20)
        self.lblRetreatCostUpperLeftLabel = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.varRetreatCostLower), anchor='w', bg='#ffef82')
        self.lblRetreatCostUpperLeftLabel.place(x=705, y=420, width=25, height=20)
        self.lblRetreatCostUpperRightLabel = tk.Label(self, text=str(self.varRetreatCostUpper), anchor='w', bg='#ffef82')
        self.lblRetreatCostUpperRightLabel.place(x=1300, y=420, width=25, height=20)
        self.lblRetreatCostRange = tk.Label(self, text='', bg='#ffef82',font=('Lucida Grande',12))
        self.lblRetreatCostRange.place(x=980, y=335, width=200, height=30)

def updatedHPLowerScale(self,* args,** kwargs):
    self.sclHPUpper.config(from_=self.sclHPLower.get())
    self.lblHPUpperLeftLabel.config(text=str(self.sclHPLower.get()))
    self.updateHPRangeLabel()

def updatedHPUpperScale(self,* args,** kwargs):
    self.sclHPLower.config(to=self.sclHPUpper.get())
    self.lblHPLowerRightLabel.config(text=str(self.sclHPUpper.get()))
    self.updateHPRangeLabel()

def updateHPRangeLabel(self):
    if self.sclHPLower.get() == self.sclHPUpper.get():
        self.lblHPRange.config(text='HP Range: {}'.format(self.sclHPUpper.get()))
    else:
        self.lblHPRange.config(text='HP Range: {} to {}'.format(self.sclHPLower.get(), self.sclHPUpper.get()))

def updatedRetreatCostLowerScale(self,* args,** kwargs):
    self.sclRetreatCostUpper.config(from_=self.sclRetreatCostLower.get())
    self.lblRetreatCostUpperLeftLabel.config(text=str(self.sclRetreatCostLower.get()))
    self.updateRetreatCostRangeLabel()

def updatedRetreatCostUpperScale(self,* args,** kwargs):
    self.sclRetreatCostLower.config(to=self.sclRetreatCostUpper.get())
    self.lblRetreatCostLowerRightLabel.config(text=str(self.sclRetreatCostUpper.get()))
    self.updateRetreatCostRangeLabel()

def updateRetreatCostRangeLabel(self):
    if self.sclRetreatCostLower.get() == self.sclRetreatCostUpper.get():
        self.lblRetreatCostRange.config(text='RetreatCost Range: {}'.format(self.sclRetreatCostUpper.get()))
    else:
        self.lblRetreatCostRange.config(text='RetreatCost Range: {} to {}'.format(self.sclRetreatCostLower.get(), self.sclRetreatCostUpper.get()))
```

As I said there are two of these (each with their own methods), I've probably just missed a misnamed variable but if you could help trackdown the source of the bugginess I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    self.varHPLower = tk.IntVar()
    self.varHPLower = 0
```

So, you're throwing away the IntVars that you create, replacing them with integers - which are NOT valid as the `variable=` option of a Slider.  You must use the `.get()` and `.set()` methods of IntVars to operate on their stored value.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea!

Comment: Just tried it out, also replaced the instances of `from_=self.varHPLower` to `from_=self.varHPLower.get()` etc and it works!